# Verification of Electric Field from Infinite Line Charge

Tags: electrostatic

**Problem:**
I am currently tackling a problem involving the derivation of the electric field \$\textbf{E}\$ at location \$(0,y)\$ induced by an infinite homogeneous line charge \$\lambda\$ (refer to the provided image below). I have formulated the integral (last equation below).

**Goal:** Prior to seeking a solution, my primary aim is to ensure the accuracy of my derivation up to the last equation.

**Question:** Could you kindly review the equation and point out any errors or suggest improvements? I am solely interested in verifying the correctness of my derivation at this stage and not seeking a solution. Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

First, let's calculate an infinitesimally small charge \$dQ\$ on the line charge:

\begin{align}
    dQ = \lambda \cdot dx
\end{align}

The electric field \$d\textbf{E}\$ generated by this infinitesimally small charge \$dQ\$  is defined as:

\begin{align}
    d\textbf{E} &= k \cdot \frac{dQ}{\Delta r^2} \cdot \frac{\Delta\textbf{r}}{\Delta r} = k \cdot \lambda \cdot \frac{dx}{\Delta r^2} \cdot \frac{\Delta \textbf{r}}{\Delta r} 
\end{align}

with the constant by Coloumb's law:

\begin{align}
k=\frac{1}{4\cdot \pi \cdot \epsilon_0} 
\end{align}

and the displacement vector from \$dQ\$ to the point \$(0,y)\$:

\begin{align}
\Delta\textbf{r}=\textbf{p}-\textbf{r}= y\cdot \hat{\textbf{y}} - (-x\cdot \hat{\textbf{x}})= y\cdot \hat{\textbf{y}} + x\cdot \hat{\textbf{x}}
\end{align}

and the magnitude of the displacement vector:

\begin{align}
\Delta r=\left|\Delta\textbf{r}\right|=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} 
\end{align}

Proceeding to evaluate the integral:

\begin{align}
    \textbf{E}  &= k \cdot \lambda \cdot \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{\Delta r^2} \cdot \frac{\Delta\textbf{r}}{\Delta r}  \,\, dx \\
    &= k \cdot \lambda \cdot \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \cdot \frac{x\cdot \hat{\textbf{x}} + y\cdot \hat{\textbf{y}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}  \,\, dx \\
    &=\color{red!60!black}{ k \cdot \lambda \cdot \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{-x\cdot \hat{\textbf{x}} + y\cdot \hat{\textbf{y}}}{(x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}  \,\, dx}
\end{align}

Comment: You should explain what lambda and k is. You also explain why you make a distinction between \$r\$ and \$\text{r}\$. I know lambda is the line charge density but, I was scratching my head about k.

Comment: @Andyaka: thank you. I edited my question. I hope its clear now.

Comment: @Andyaka: How to render inline LaTeX equations here in this forum? BR

Comment: The electric field intensity due to an infinite line of positive charge is: |E|=λ/(2πεy) and is directed along y.  The potential difference between two points at radial distances r2 and r1 with r2>r1 is:  V21=λln(r2/r1)/(2πε)

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer here's an example \$k=\dfrac{1}{4\cdot\pi\cdot\epsilon_0}\$ = `\$k=\dfrac{1}{4\cdot\pi\cdot\epsilon_0}\$`

Comment: @Franc: thanks a lot but please note that I do not need the final solution. I do need to know if the integral (last equation) is correct or not.

Comment: It's an exercise that you can find in all physics and electromagnetics texts. You don't need to ask on this site.

Comment: @Franc: Ok than it should be easy. is my last equation correct? because i could not find it in any book the way I didi it.

Comment: It seems correct to me. In the integrand, the term in x is symmetric with respect to the y axis so the integral is zero. However, the integral with respect to x of the term in y is not zero. If you had chosen an x on the positive axis, you would have the same result.

Comment: @Franc: thanks. you can reply to my question then I can upvote and accept your answer

Comment: I would highlight on the graph the vector E aligned with the unit vector r and its two orthogonal components. I would also define r as the position vector. The formulas are correct.

Comment: @Franc: I have implemented the modifications you suggested. I hope the content has improved. Best regards.

Comment: @Franc: Can you please check the displacement \$\Delta\textbf{r}\$ vector equation.

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to the previous graph, the current one is not acceptable.
[image]

Comment: What is not correct with my Drawing?

Comment: r is a vector with a magnitude equal to the distance from the point (0,y) to the infinitesimal charge element. Δr is a difference vector with infinitesimal modulus.